# Way to increase query performance

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have a query like below for which i need to improve query performance.

```
select col1,col2
from view1 
join tab1
on view1.col1=tab1.col1 and view1.col2=tab1.col2 and tab1.col3='ABC';
```

Table tab1 is big having half a million records. And i think that's why oracle optimizer is going for a full table scan on tab1. Even if i create a index on (col1,col2,col3) of tab1, optimizer still goes for full table scan. Due to this query takes more time(more than 30 sec). I have a threshold of 30 sec and need to bring down the time below 30 sec.
Is there a way to bring down query time below 30 sec even with full table scan ?
Do i need to use any other index.

view1

```
    select col1,col2 from tab2 left outer join tab3 on tab2.col1=tab3.col1
```

Comment: (1) Your query will generate an error in Oracle (no `on` clause).  (2) Performance is probably based on the "view".  Without knowing what that is, you probably can't do anything.

Comment: FTS(Full Table Scan) is not bad because sometimes that's the most optimal way of getting the data but it depends on how many total rows are in the table and how many are having value COL3 = 'ABC', you can try index hint to force table to use index on column but best if you can provide more details like explain plan, table and view structure and indexes.

Comment: i tried adding index hint. Still optimizer goes for FTS

Comment: can you provide an explain plan of your query ?

Comment: What is the ratio of rows in `tab1` that have the text `'ABC'` in `col1` compared to total number of rows?  Hint:  If more than around 10% of total rows, (I think) Oracle won't read an index.  If you query just `tab1` without joining to the view, and with the   `'ABC'` criteria, how fast does that run?  As @RobertoHernandez says, we really need an explain plan to give a reasonable answer.